# How to check if my bot has permission to view a voice channel before trying to join it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to check if my Discord bot has permission to join a voice channel before attempting to connect to it. I'm using the Python `discord` API. I tried passing in the `Bot.user` object to `VoiceChannel.permissions_for()` function but it requires a `Member` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get member object for the bot user, you can use `ctx.guild.me`. It will return the member object if command is called in a guild.